# How to print the result of my pymongo.cursor.Cursos object?

Tags: python, pymongo

This is my code so far:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.local
collection = db.orderbook_update
orderbook = collection.find({
    "lastUpdated": {"$lt": ts}
}).sort("position",pymongo.DESCENDING).limit(1)
print(orderbook)
```

When I do that, my print(orderbook) gives me that: `<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7ff7defef828>`
How am I able to print my result in order to use it? My json file on my database has three main components: lastUpdated, asks, bids. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
order = list(orderbook)
```

**Note: Once you do do this cursor object will not be available**

Comment: Whilst this might answer the question, it is better practice to explain the code to help any future visitors with a similar issue.

Comment: >All python Generator/cursor objects can only be retrieved only through "for" loops.
It is wrong. What about `next(iter(orderbook))`

Comment: Yeah, that's another way of doing it.

Comment: @DomnicAmalan please edit your post to fix incorrect terms.